# How to get cold start metrics in flutter app for Android build?

Tags: android, flutter, performance, dart, cold-start

I want to measure TTID and TTFD,
For TTFD i will add my custom trace ( if you have any ideas feel free to share),but for TTID android builds by default gives a displayed tag in the logcat with time taken.
I am assuming that is the best right wah to check TTID for flutter app for Android build, please correct me if I'm wrong here.
So i want to use this value now in my code and send this data to my dashboard which I am creating.